# docker search: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided

Tags: docker

When I try to search some image (i.e., `mysql`) via `docker search mysql`, I get the title error:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=mysql: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided
```

My Env infos:

```
Docker version: Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca
Host: Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
```

How to fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/metacontroller/issues/86): `x509` means you need to install `ca-certificates`, which usually happened when you want to visit https link:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
```